# Elastic search concatenation of fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and wanted to solve an use case with below problem

I have some documents as below format

```
{
 "member_id":"number"
 "e_id":"number",
 "c_id":"number",
 "salary":"float"
}
```

In my Java application, I will get a String input and need to find the matching document's **member_id**. The algorithm to find the document is as below

STEP 1:  *Take input string as "keyInput".*
STEP 2: *Concat "e_id","c_id" and ceil("salary")  as "concatedData"* 
STEP 3:  *if "concatedData" equals to "keyInput" THEN return the "member_id" of the matching document.*

STEP 2 need to be performed in Elasticsearch.

Can anyone help to figure out if this kind of actions can be performed on ES or not, if Yes then how?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should alter your indexing process to index this concat data in elasticsearch already

Comment: or you can use a scripted query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), but really you should create the concatenated data during indexation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this.

#### 1. Using script:

Suggested Mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "member_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "e_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "c_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "salary": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "String.valueOf(doc['e_id'].value) + doc['c_id'].value + Math.ceil(doc['salary'].value).intValue() == params.inp",
            "lang": "painless",
            "params": {
              "inp": "12345678"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Scripting should be avoided as it cause performance hit. I would strongly recommend the second approach below.

#### 2. By concatenating value at index time

For this all you need to do is add a new field with datatype as `keyword` to store the concatenated value. Then use `term query` to filter the documents accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Nishant. I just changed from "source" to "inline" in your solution and it worked for me.